# Preventing R to drop a specific column in data frame list

Tags: r, dataframe, list, dplyr

I am currently working on a list with a couple of large data frames containing behavioural data of a couple of mice. Most of the variables are junk, so I wrote this function to mass drop variables containing strings, empty variables, and those who have no variance to them.

```
df_clean <- function(x){                    
  if(!require(caret)){
    install.packages('caret')
    library(caret)
  }
  
  if(!require(tidyverse)){
    install.packages('tidyverse')
    library(tidyverse)
  }
  
  x <- 
    x %>%
    discard(~ all(is.na(.) | . == ''))      # removes all empty columns; requires tidyverse
  x <- 
    dplyr::select_if(x, is.numeric)         # removes non-numeric columns
  y <- 
    nearZeroVar(x, saveMetrics = T) %>%     # searches for and saves zero variance columns
    filter(zeroVar == T) %>%
    row.names()
  x <- 
    x %>% 
    select(- one_of(y))                     # removes other unnecessary columns
  x <- 
    x %>%
    rename_with(make.names)                 # replaces spaces in variables names with .
  return(x)
}
```

This works quite well and I can drop a lot of columns very fast. However, one column is affected by this that I want to keep. It has basically no variance because it just indicates the session number (variable name is literally "Session No"). I have tried extracting the session numbers from the data frames prior to applying the function and then reinserting them again like this:

```
habit_2302_T1_session_no <-
  df_list[[8]][[12]]; pbs_2302_T1_session_no <-
  df_list[[11]][[12]]
habit_2303_T1_session_no <-
  df_list[[9]][[12]]; amph_2303_T1_session_no <-
  df_list[[12]][[12]]
habit_2304_T1_session_no <-
  df_list[[10]][[12]]; amph_2304_T1_session_no <-
  df_list[[13]][[12]]

T1_session_no <- 
  list(
    habit_2302_T1_session_no,
    habit_2303_T1_session_no, 
    habit_2304_T1_session_no,
    pbs_2302_T1_session_no,
    amph_2303_T1_session_no,
    amph_2304_T1_session_no
  )

df_list <- lapply(df_list, df_clean)

# loop to insert variables again
for(i in 2:length(df_list)){
  for(j in 1:length(T1_session_no)){
    df_list[[i]] %>%
      add_column(
        Time.point = 0,
        Condition = NA,
        Session.No = T1_session_no[[j]]
      )
  }
}
```

However, this throws me the following error:

> Error in `add_column()`:
> New columns must be compatible with `.data`.
> New columns have 180 rows.
> ℹ `.data` has 60 rows.
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Since this is quite a bit of code and just seems inefficient, I was wondering if there was another way of addressing the issue, i.e. preventing R to drop the variable "Session No" in the first place instead of extracting it and then reinserting it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `x <- x %>%  select(- one_of(y), 'Session No.')`  might work to exclude the zero var columns BUT include "Session No.", or `x <- x %>%  select(- one_of(y), contains('session_no'))` if it has variations it its name.

Comment: The second option using `contains()` worked. Thanks a lot, Jon!